# Get data outside HTML object

Tags: jquery, html, object

I have an HTML page with a couple of divs with data in it:

```
<div class="event-name">Event x</div>
<div class="event-date">21 november 2017</div>
<div class="event-address">full address here</div>
```

On this page is a form that is loaded into it with:

```
jQuery(".tribe-events-tickets.tribe-events-tickets-rsvp").html('<object data="http://www.page-form.com/"/>');
```

On that page (so the external url), I have some scripts to get the values from the divs above. When the form on the external page is submitted, I do this:

```
html_name = jQuery('.event-name').html();
$('#mce-SESNAAM').val(html_name);
```

But that doesn't seem to work because the form is in an object/external page.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you pass parameters to that page?

Comment: I hope so - I've created a script that pushes the data into parameters. Now I hope that the other party can implement that script. If so, I can use $_GET['name'] in the value attributes of the hidden fields

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it to work :-)

The third party added my JS script to the website. That script added variables to the iframe and replaced the current form.

```
      jQuery(".tribe-events").html('<iframe src="http://my-form.be/?name='+ html_name +'&place='+ html_place +'&hour='+ html_hour +'&date='+ mc_date +'"></iframe>');
```

In form http://my-form.be/

```
       <input type="hidden" name="session_name" id="mce-SESNAAM" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>" />
```

This works perfectly.